# Every Assembly program using the Win32 API's print function equivalents crashes on startup. How can I fix this?

Tags: function, assembly, binary, call

I tried messing around with Win32 binaries lately (this is for a big project of mine).
So after some weeks of research, I now have a solid understanding of how Assembly works, how it is converted into binary code and how x86/x64 opcodes work.

The last piece to the puzzle is figuring out how to properly call Win32 API methods.
I actually asked a question on here in relation to this, and the answer I got was, I should try and compile an Assembly or C program that does this. So I went ahead and tried this in Assembly (I'm using FASM by the way):

```
format PE console
entry start

section '.idata' import data readable writable
    include 'win32a.inc'

    library kernel,'kernel32.dll'


    import kernel,\
           GetStdHandle,'GetStdHandle',\
           WriteConsoleA,'WriteConsoleA'

section '.data' data readable writable
    string db 'Hello!', 0h
    output dd ?

section '.code' code readable executable
    start:  push -11
            call GetStdHandle

            pushd 0
            pushd output
            pushd 7
            pushd string
            pushd eax
            call WriteConsoleA
```

This is one of the many versions of this code actually. The main problem is, when I call methods like "ExitProcess", generally other functions from the kernel32.dll library, things seem to work out. It's the IO functions that bug me...

I don't understand what's wrong with this code, I don't get any compile-time errors, though when I run it, it just crashes.

So my next idea was, since this didn't work, to try the same in C.
I'm using Cygwin as a compiler and linker...

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello, world!", "Test", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

This code yielded the same result, the application crashed.

Now, I am not looking for any C/C++ code. My original question of interest was to know how calling extern library function looks like in x86/x64 binary (assembled) code. But I would be very thankful for any resources regarding this topic.

Thank you in advance.

-Tom S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to call `ExitProcess` at the end to properly end the process. Since you are not doing that, the code currently will continue executing and eventually segfaults because it attempts to execute junk bytes.

Comment: Actually, `ExitProcess` is *not* required - you can just return from the entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks! For the assembly code, this actually works. But i do not understand why the C code won't work after all. I mean, I took this code from a beginner tutorial.

Comment: I can't see a reason the C code will crash. Unless the character set is defined to Unicode right now?